# Page loads too slow because of Wistia embedded videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, wistia

My website is having lots of Wistia videos, embedded in an iframe, whenever I load my page for the first time, It's taking a lot of time which makes my website slow, Is there any way I can load the video whenever I click on that particular videos.

This is small code snippet

```
<ul> 
 <li>
    <a href="#" class="toggle">Operations</a>
    <ul class="inner ulmargin">
    <iframe src=" https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/b8?seo=false" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" id="wistia_4d8229898d"  name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="280" height="200"></iframe>
   </ul>
 </li>
<ul>
```

Above is just an example of one video, I have lots of videos inside that **UL** command. 
Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try lazy loading

Comment: @Rob All my list of videos are inside one div, If I apply this all of my videos will load.

Comment: @GaneshPutta, can you tell me where I will find something about lazy loading

Comment: Iframes load async defer by default. You should use javascript and place the iframes sequentially on page load (complete)

Comment: try with my code as a sample for lazy loading

Comment: lazy loading is a term used to load content after the main content has loaded

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here, here i have many videos. But it loads fast, copy my code and paste in a html file and run

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
html {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 680px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.youtube {
    background-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.youtube img {
    width: 100%;
    top: -16.82%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.youtube .play-button {
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #333;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba( 0,0,0,0.6 );
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.youtube .play-button:before {
    content: "";
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 15px 0 15px 26.0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
}
.youtube img,
.youtube .play-button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.youtube img,
.youtube iframe,
.youtube .play-button,
.youtube .play-button:before {
    position: absolute;
}
.youtube .play-button,
.youtube .play-button:before {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate3d( -50%, -50%, 0 );
}
.youtube iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/><div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="youtube" data-embed="AqcjdkPMPJA">
        <div class="play-button"></div>
    </div>
</div><br/>
<script>
( function() {

var youtube = document.querySelectorAll( ".youtube" );

for (var i = 0; i < youtube.length; i++) {

var source = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+ youtube[i].dataset.embed +"/sddefault.jpg";

var image = new Image();
image.src = source;
image.addEventListener( "load", function() {
youtube[ i ].appendChild( image );
}( i ) );

youtube[i].addEventListener( "click", function() {

var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );

        iframe.setAttribute( "frameborder", "0" );
        iframe.setAttribute( "allowfullscreen", "" );
        iframe.setAttribute( "src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+ this.dataset.embed +"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1" );

        this.innerHTML = "";
        this.appendChild( iframe );
} );    
};

} )();
</script>
```

Comment: will this work for wistia videos?

Comment: Thanks, Code is working with Wistia videos as well, Now I have to implement in my code